# Does `transform` actually affect the calculation of `offsetLeft`? If so, what is the mechanism?

Tags: css, position, transform, offset

If there is the following `HTML` and `CSS`:

```html
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
  html {
    padding: 30px;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
  }

  .root {
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #8f8;
  }

  .container {
    /* position: relative; */

    padding: 200px;
    background-color: #88f;

    transform: translate(0);
  }

  .box {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #f88;
  }
```

then I get the `offsetLeft` of `div.box` like this:

```js
  const boxOffsetLeft = document.querySelector('.box').offsetLeft
  console.log('boxOffsetLeft:', boxOffsetLeft) // 200
```

The value of `boxOffsetLeft` is `200`, which is the same as the result when I set `position: relative;`. In other words, for `offsetLeft`, setting `transform` can achieve the same effect as setting `position: relative;`.

I have looked up the relevant specification documents, and this is how `offsetLeft` is described in the [CSSOM View Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetleft):

> The offsetLeft attribute must return the result of running these steps:
>
> 1. If the element is the body element or does not have any associated box return zero and terminate this algorithm.
> 2. If the offsetParent of the element is null return the x-coordinate of the left border edge of the first box associated with the element, relative to the initial containing block origin, ignoring any transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors, and terminate this algorithm.
> 3. Return the result of subtracting the x-coordinate of the left padding edge of the first box associated with the offsetParent of the element from the x-coordinate of the left border edge of the first box associated with the element, relative to the initial containing block origin, ignoring any transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors.

My question is: Does `transform` actually affect the calculation of `offsetLeft`? If so, what is the mechanism?

Comment: transform establishes a containing block.